# using and stopping threading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

with this code, i want to start the strt() on time 01:46, and run logging() every 10 sec till time 01:47.
but i am not able to stop the thread when now > end time
i cant get whats wrong here
i just want the thread to stop

```
def strt():
    print("aa")

    def loging():
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        endtime = now.replace(hour=1, minute=47, second=0, microsecond=0)
        t = threading.Timer(10, loging)
        if now < endtime:
            print("bb")
            print(time.ctime())
            t.start()
        else:
            t.cancel()

    loging()


schedule.every().day.at("01:46").do(strt)
while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: there are some more lines after logging()...but it is not shown as part of code in my question

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are checking once whether `now < endtime`, start the thread, and never check the time again.

Comment: I tried to fix your indendation, please check yourself whether it is correct now and edit your question if needed.

Comment: @timgeb every 10sec, i want to check now < endtime. if now > endtime, loging should stop. And sorry for the indentation. i fixed it

Comment: Does either of these things work in separation? In that case, your code is not a [mcve] and you should edit your question. Anyhow, please make the code complete so that it can be verified. In particular, it doesn't help that there is a function `loging()` while your question references one call `logging()`!